# How to get Resttemplate Bean in Entity class using autowired

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, resttemplate

i am trying to write a method in my Entity class before populating the properties of entity class. To Do that i need to call a rest service . I like to bring my resttemplate into my Entity class using Autowired . Is that something possible , If yes how we can do that .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IC_ORDER")
public class ICOrder implements Serializable {

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "UUIDGenerator", strategy = "uuid2")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "UUIDGenerator")
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
UUID id;

@Transient
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@SneakyThrows
int start(Context context,String userId) {

//restTemplate.postForEntity // Trying to call a rest service here . But getting 
restTemplate as null , Want to avoid new Resttemplate here.

}
```

This is the code in Config class

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
return builder.build();
```

}

Comment: Please do not do that, such logic should not live inside of an entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities belong to the domain layer. It is better to make them not depends on any external framework or library stuff such as `RestTemplate` as much as you can. Also, having the domain layer interacts with the external systems directly just does not feel right to me. They should be done in a higher level layer such as service layer. So it is better to have a separate service class like `OrderService` to do such logic. You can then easily inject the `RestTemplate` into this service class.

If you insist doing it inside the domain model , please checkout [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-bean-into-unmanaged-objects#injecting-a-bean-into-a-jpa-entity) for how to use `@Configurable` and AspectJ to do it.

Comment: Thanks. That works and yes i am forced to do this . I can’t change the structure now.